# using automator/applescript to upload files to a web form?

Tags: applescript, automator

I have a bunch of files I want to upload to web page. Unfortunately the web form for uploading only allows me to specify one at a time (it spawns and 'open file' dialog). Is there an easy way to do this with some combination of automator/applescirpt?

Comment: This is very site-specific, can you add some details about the site (address if public, screenshots)?

Comment: It's mind42.com. It's html/javascript driven. I was hoping to achieve a series of clicks at specific screen positions (which I could perhaps record with automator?), the last of which would open a 'file upload' dialog. Then navigate to the correct folder and perhaps paste in the name of the next file to upload. This would be repeated for each of the files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to get automator to do what I wanted, with a little help from `grep` ;)

I did it with a 'workflow' and a "files and folders" in "finder" service. The service calls the workflow with each of the selected file names.

Here's what the service does:

- `Run Shell Script` with Pass input `to stdin` and the script `grep -o '[^/]*$'`  --  the service receives the full paths of the files selected in the finder, I only want the file names, so this removes the path bit.
- `Launch Application` with `firefox`  -- this seems to be the best way to switch applications (even if they're already open..)
- `Run Workflow` - `in batches` of `1` at a time using `1` workflow, with "wait for workflow to finish" ticked.

The `in batches` mode appears to process text input line by line. Each line output by `grep` contains a file name, so the second workflow is called once with each file name. Note that the list of file names is passed through `Launch Application`.

Here's what the workflow does:

- `Copy to Clipboard`
- a recorded `Watch Me Do`:

  - a series of clicks to get the 'upload file' dialog up
  - a click to focus it's search box,\
  - paste (the file name)
  - select the top found file
  - click 'open'
  - a series of clicks to upload the file and return the page to the same state in which we started

There were a few hiccups along the way.

- First I used `command-V` to paste, but for some reason that was unreliable, so I ended up using paste from the edit menu instead.
- I had to be careful to leave enough time between clicks for worst-case rendering of html pages and opening dialogs etc..
- When the flow crashed (usually by getting out of sync with the browser), I often ended up with the browser stuck with the 'upload file' dialog open and unresponsive. To get it responsive again, I found that moving it sufficed (ie: dragging it's title bar a bit).

Comment: Any chance you can share your Automator file? Thanks!

Comment: Happy to share it - do you know a good place to do that? I've [asked a question](http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/142837/where-is-a-good-place-to-share-automator-files) too...

Comment: Could you please share it with me as well? This is exactly what I was looking for. Probably a one-click hoster would work best?

Comment: @BalassaSamuelson Afraid I'm a bit busy at the moment... If you manage to put it together using the instructions above, perhaps you could share it somewhere and provide a link?

Answer (score 2):

I followed @drevickos very good instructions. Didn't manage it with Safari, but Firefox works perfectly. 
Below the downloads for the Service file `UploadFilesWebForm` and the Automator file `UploadFirefox3`.

With these files, I managed to upload multiple files to SAS on AWS. 
For any other website, you should adjust:

- `Watch me do` procedure to fit your web form in the `UploadFirefox3` file
- The `delay` needed for upload specified in the `UploadFirefox3` file

UploadFilesWebForm.workflow.zip
http://www45.zippyshare.com/v/QQm0SKJ5/file.html
UploadFirefox3.workflow.zip
http://www45.zippyshare.com/v/bHyKGi2g/file.html

Comment: thx - been meaning to do that for a long time, but life keeps getting in the way! (:

Comment: Those links are dead - but the workflows look interesting...