# Where is a good place to share automator files

Tags: automator, websites

I've had a [request to share an Automator workflow](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/82201/using-automator-applescript-to-upload-files-to-a-web-form/82317?noredirect=1#comment167675_82317) I made. Where is a good place to do that? Something like pastebin but for workflow files.

Comment: Create a GitHub repo for your work..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gists on github are a great way to do that. Or just share the repo that contains the file on github.